# Save the scroll position in sideBar when refreshing the page

Tags: javascript

I want to keep the scroll position in the sidebar, but I can't figure out what the error is. What did I do wrong in the JS script?

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebarHeader">
        <h4 class="courseHeader"></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebarMain">
        <ul class="sidebarUl">
            <li class="sidebarLi">
                <a class = "sidebarA" href="1.2.html">1.2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sidebarLi">
                <a class = "sidebarA" href="2.1.html">2.1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".sidebarA", function() {
var sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");

sidebar.scroll(0, localStorage.getItem('scrollPosition')|0);


sidebar.scroll(function () {
       localStorage.setItem('scrollPosition', sidebar.scrollTop)
});});
```

Answer (score 1):

`Element#scroll` does not take a function as argument so you are never saving the new position anywhere.

What you want to do instead is to listen for the scroll event:

```js
sidebar.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  console.log(sidebar.scrollTop);
});
```

- [`Element#scroll` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll)
- [`Element#scroll_event` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event)

Another thing:

`Element#querySelectorAll` doesn't take a function as argument either; so

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".sidebarA", function() { /* Stuff */ });
```

won't run the function you put there as a callback. If the goal is to run the code inside that function after the page has loaded, you can use the load event:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var sidebar // and so on...
});
```

Answer (score -1):

here is some change in your js code, be sure that `sidebarUl` class must look like

```
.sidebarUl {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100px;
}
```

and parent element has css prop `overflow:hidden`

```
const element = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebarUl')[0]
console.log('element', element)
element.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  console.log('e', e.target.scrollTop);
  localStorage.setItem('scrollPosition', e.target.scrollTop)
});

window.onload = function() {
  const element = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebarUl')[0]
  var reloading = sessionStorage.getItem("scrollPosition");
  if (reloading != 0) {
    element.scroll(0, localStorage.getItem('scrollPosition')|0);
  }
}
```